# Python: How to connect BLE device when i use bleak module

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-runtime

I trying example of bleak dev team. But the device used to connect twice yesterday but since yesterday afternoon it can't connect again. According to the documentation ADVERTISING its 10.248s. I tried 20s but still can't connect to  asyncTimeouterror

```
import asyncio
import platform
import sys

import bleak.exc
from bleak import BleakClient, BleakScanner
from bleak.exc import BleakError


ADDRESS = (
    "F5:8B:A2:4C:AD:9C"
    if platform.system() != "Darwin"
    else "B9EA5233-37EF-4DD6-87A8-2A875E821C46"
)


async def main(ble_address: str):
    try:
        device = await BleakScanner.find_device_by_address(ble_address, timeout=10.0)
        if not device:
            raise BleakError(f"A device with address {ble_address} could not be found.")
        async with BleakClient(device, timeout=22.0) as client:
            print("Services:")
            for service in client.services:
                print(service)
    except bleak.exc.BleakError as e:
        print(e)

while True:
    asyncio.run(main(sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) == 2 else ADDRESS))
```

I think the problem is with the advertising time but I have tried with many different timeouts but it doesn't work

Comment: What OS are you running this script on? Linux, macOS, or Windows?

Comment: I am running the application on windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check:

- whether the device is using or not a constant MAC address
- whether your device is visible or not (using for example nRFConnect to scan from you mobile in parallel). Some device can only manage a single connection and not visible if you are already connected (for example if you are bonded to it). Also Bleak does not retrieve the list of device already connected
- whether you can see your device in a simple scan (without filtering on device BLE address). if so you can validate if the device has the same MAC address or not. If the Mac address changes, you can find another filtering criteria (services available, name...)